# Shell script to specify a user is logged into computer

Tags: shell

```
username=$1
freq=$2

checkuser()
{
  if who grep "$1"
  then
  sleep 60
  fi
}

if [ -n "$1" ]
then
echo "Enter username"
read username
checkuser
echo -e "$1 is logged on \a"
echo -e "$1 logged in at `date`">>LOG
checkuser
else
echo "User is not logged on"
fi
```

I need to integrate a second argument into my code which allows for the user to specify after what time should the script check to see who is logged in. I have it set to 60 seconds currently and this needs to be the default frequency. I tried to use another function but to no avail. I thought of something like this...

```
if [ "$2" -ne 0 ]
then
freq=$2
else
freq=60
```

Thanks William for that was very helpful!! I changed the code a bit and came up with this. I now need to add a 3rd argument "X" which when selected just sends a message to the LOGFILE and not to the screen. I made an attempt but not doing as intended.

```
 username=$1
 freq=${2:-10}
 X=$3

 checkuser()
 {
 whoami|grep "$1";
 }

 while checkuser "$username"
 do
 echo -e "$1 is logged on \a"
 echo "$1 logged in at `date`">>LOGFILE
 sleep $freq
 exit 0
 done
 echo "User is not logged in"

 if [ "$3" -ne 1 ]
 then
 echo "$1 logged in at `date`"LOGFILE
 fi
```

Answer (score 1):

```
username=$1
freq=${2:-60} # Set a default frequency

checkuser(){ who | grep -q "$1"; }

while ! checkuser "$username"; do
    echo "User is not logged on"    
    sleep $freq
done
echo "$1 is logged on"
```

Also note that you can simplify the setting of username:

```
username=${1:-$( echo "Enter username: "; read u; echo $u; )}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo 'Enter id'
read id
res=`who | grep "$id" | wc -l` 
if [ $res -eq 0 ]
then
    echo 'user is not logged in'
else
    echo 'user is logged in'
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple shell script that takes the username as input and determines whether the user is currently logged in.

```
if [[ $# -eq 0 ]]; then
    echo "Usage: " $0 "username"
    exit 1
fi

result="$(who | grep $1 | wc -l)"

if [[ $result -gt 0 ]]; then
    echo "$1 is currently logged in"
else
    echo "$1 is not logged in"
fi

exit 0
```